# How to map in Slick MySQL TINYINT(1) column?

Tags: scala, slick

Is it ok to map MySQL column of type `TINYINT(1)` as

`def deleted = column[Boolean]("deleted")`

in Slick?

When I map the column this way then it is not working as I would expect in filters like one below:

```
def cleanUpDeletedSegments(implicit db:ADMPDB)={
    db.run{
      segments.filter(_.deleted === true).delete
    }
```

}

Comment: could you be more specific? are you getting any issue with you example?

Comment: @Pavel, I ask because I've mapped that way and when I tried to use this column in filters it did not work as I would expect. In standard examples I cannot see anything about this specific case of using TINYINT(1) in MySQL for boolean columns.

Comment: I would suspect you would need to dig in the sources to find the answer, current slick documentation is very brief

Comment: I probably would do this, if in some time no one provides any answer based on their experience. But I am not sure my level of knowledge will really suffice to read Slick sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've tried I can conclude that `TINYINT(1)` will not map to `Boolean`.

I have changed mapping to `def deleted = column[Int]("deleted")` and filtering just by ===1 or ===0.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the slick codegen in 3.2.3 automatically creates this field as a Boolean.  Which, is wrong.

Comment: @PlexQ, by the way, could you share your approach when you need to work with fields which logically have `Boolean` type? At the moment I use `BIT` type in MySQL and custom apply/unapply in my Slick projections. But probably there is some column type in MySQL which will be automatically mapped to Scala's `Boolean` and I just not aware of this?

Answer (score 0):

I am just playing with v3.3.1, and `Boolean` **does** work for `Tinyint(1)`